# Uncertainty principle, Sobolev embedding, and norm estimates

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Terence Tao offers a nice discussion of different function spaces in [this blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-type-diagram-for-function-spaces/). In the blog there is an explanation of the tradeoff between regularity $s$ and integrability $p$, where $s,p$ are exponents for Sobolev spaces $W^{s,p}, H^{s,p}$, or other similar function spaces. We can gain more integrability (that is, increase $p$), by sacrificing regularity $s.$ This is known as Sobolev injection. The idea behind it is the uncertainty principle.

There are, however, other forms of uncertainty principle. The most famous quatitative version is probably
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^N)} \|xu\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^N)} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^N)}^2.
$$

And we can always be creative and prove **many** other versions of the uncertainty principle, showing the same idea of a tradeoff between regularity and integrability.

So, **what are some other forms of the uncertainty principle, and is there an estimate that capture the essence of this idea even better than the $L^2$ norm estimate and Sobolev embedding?** (that is, one which is more fundamental?)

Comment: I just wanted to note that if you assume that the $L^2$ norm of $u$ is $1$ (by rescaling) and set $f = u^2$, then the inequality above is a special case of the Cramer-Rao inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound)